# jQuery Bug - Bind an event from iframe to parent.window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, iframe

I have two pages: parent.html and child.html.
child.html is included in parent.html with an iframe.

The child.html page bind a scroll event on its parent.window in order to detect when a scroll event is triggered at the top level. The child page set a property on the parent.window in order to display and update an increment each time the scroll event is triggered.

Here is the code of the two pages:

Page parent.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
  <iframe border="1" src="child.html"></iframe>
  <div style="height:1600px; width:300px; background:gray;">
    A div just here to activate the scrollbar
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Page child:

```
<html>
  <body>    
  <a target="_self" href="">Reload this page</a>     
  <div class="test"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    parent.window.increment = 1;
    var onScroll = function (event) {
      parent.window.increment++;
      $('.test').html(parent.window.increment);
    };
    $(parent.window).off('scroll');
    $(parent.window).on('scroll', onScroll);
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### The problem with this setup is the following :

**On Chrome (it works on Firefox)**, if you load the page for the first time the parent.window.increment is correctly incremented by 1 each time a scroll event is detected (when the parent page scrollbar is moved). But if you press on the "Reload" link the parent.window.increment is no more incremented by one when a scroll event is triggered but by two. If you press again on the Reload link the increment property is incremented by 3, etc.

**A working example can be found here : http://jsfiddle.net/cm0s/ngZkq/16/.**

I'm not really looking for a solution (the code I posted is just an example of a problem I'm facing in another project). I'd rather like to understand what's happening. If I'm making a rookie mistake?

**Here are two things I really don't understand :**

**1. parent.window.increment not reset**

I don't understand why the increment property is not always reset to 1. When we press on the "Reload" link the following line is always executed :

```
parent.window.increment = 1;
```

**2. Works on Firefox but not on Chrome**

What I also don't understand is why it doesn't work on Chrome but works fine on Firefox.     With Firefox if you try the [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cm0s/ngZkq/16/) and click multiple times on the Reload link the parent.window.increment is always incremented by 1 when you move the scroll bar.

### EDIT NOTE:

I also created a fiddle to show the same problem with a click event :
http://jsfiddle.net/cm0s/WYy6U/3/

And another one which use the onscroll javascript function (as explained by @hex494D49) and thus works perfectly in all browsers :
http://jsfiddle.net/cm0s/D6j5G/1/

### EDIT NOTE 2:

I posted a ticket on the jquery bug tracker: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/15204.

The ticket has been closed. The bug has been described as "an unusual browser behavior".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just might found a bug in jQuery :) or at least a weird behavior of jQuery's `onscroll` event implementation. Perhaps, this could be a shorter answer on your both questions but let's analyze this behavior in more details.

If you add this `console.log(parent.window.increment);` in your code, you will see that at the first time Chrome is increasing the value of `increment` value just fine; but at the second time, the amount of the scroll is increasing by two as following `1-2, 3-4, 5-6, ...` and that's way the `increment` value within the `div` seem disordered (like 2, 4, 6, ...); at the third time Chrome starts skipping steps like this `2-3, 5-6, 8-9, 11-12, ...` and the values within the `div` came in as 3, 6, 9, 12, ...; at the fourth time values goes like this `3-4, 7-8, 11-12, 15-16, ...` which makes the `increment` value within the `div` even more fuzzy.

On the other hand, the snippet above works fine in Firefox but the amount of scroll isn't increasing by 1 but at least by 5 and this could be seen only observing the console. Maybe this could be adjusted - I tried to change a few values related to `scroll` in Firefox `about:config` section but without success so far.

Then I just thought I could change your snippet a bit (excluding jQuery) and here we are - the snippet below works just as expected in all browsers. The scroll amount on Firefox is still about 5 but you'll see that the `increment` value on reload is always resetting to `0` and there are no skippings as mentioned in case with jQuery snippet.

```
// Modified code of child.html (iframe) file

// HTML
<a target="_self" href="">Reload this page</a>     
<div id="test"></div>

// JavaScript
parent.window.increment = 0;
parent.window.onscroll = function(){
    parent.window.increment++;
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = parent.window.increment;
    console.log(parent.window.increment);
};
```

Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ngZkq/21/) (Tested on IE, Firefox, Chrome and Opera)

`EDIT:` As @NicolasForney (the OP) says in the meantime in his edit section, the same weird behavior is experienced using `onclick` event. I'd like to add that the same would be avoided not using jQuery, just as shown in the previous case with `onscroll` event.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<a target="_self" href="">Reload this page</a>
<div id="counter"></div>

// JavaScript
parent.window.counter = 0;
parent.window.onclick = function(){
    parent.window.counter++;
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = parent.window.counter;
    console.log(parent.window.counter);
};
```

Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WYy6U/7/) (Tested as above)

This definitely leads to a bug which should be explored in more details in the meantime...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
You definitely found the source of the problem. I didn't think it could be an issue with jQuery.
However, I don't think it's a problem with the scroll event. If I use a click function the same problem appear. Perhaps a problem with the bind/unbind/on/off functions.  I will have to check a bit more to find exactly what is causing the problem in order to issue a bug (if it's really one)

Comment: @NicolasForney Thanks man :) I spent about three hours to test and found out the above. You should make this issue public on jQuery's site. I really think it's a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the time you spent on this issue. It's so useful to get help from the community when we are stuck on an issue.

Comment: @NicolasForney I read your updated question, and also added a small update to my answer. Well, this is getting fun but also serious :) Maybe you could add something more catchy to the title, like 'Bug in jQuery?' or similar 'cause I think this would be a quite valuable experience for the others. In the meantime I'll try to find out more about this issue...

Comment: I changed the title and I also posted a message on the jQuery Forum. The message must first be moderated to be published. I will put a link to it later on.